# What do you use to create drawable resources? (Best practice)

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a number of PNG images which I convert to different resolutions using a bash script that I wrote.

The input is an image and output is a number of scaled images with resolutions that match: drawable-xhdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi.

Is there a better way of scaling icons and PNG images? What do you use? Should I be using SVG images instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some of your drawable resources, you may want to use 9-patch images. Ex: If u are setting a custom background for a button. This link explains briefly what 9 patch images are and how to create them. [Simple 9patch images guide](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/)

Answer (score 1):

There is  [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) from Google

Answer (score 1):

We use svg for most our icons and export to different resolutions with a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script export a .svg to different android resolution classes.
# Christian Beier, shoutrLabs
#

# Export individual svg to png with inkscape
# $1 = File
# $2 = Size 
# $3 = destination dir
function exportFile {
    FILE=$1
    SIZE=$2
    DESTDIR=$3

    echo 
    echo '################### EXPORTING '$FILE $SIZE $DESTDIR' ...'

    if [ -e $FILE ]; then

        EXPORTFILE=`basename $FILE .svg`
        EXPORTFILE=$EXPORTFILE".png"

        # If format is WIDTHxHEIGHT do this, else assume 1:1 ratio
        if [ `echo $SIZE | grep -E '^[0-9]+x[0-9]+$'` ]; then
            SIZEWIDTH=`echo $SIZE | sed 's/x[0-9]*//'`
            SIZEHEIGHT=`echo $SIZE | sed 's/[0-9]*x//'`
        else
            SIZEWIDTH=$SIZE
            SIZEHEIGHT=$SIZE
        fi

        mkdir -p $DESTDIR
        inkscape --without-gui --file=$FILE --export-area-drawing --export-png="$DESTDIR/$EXPORTFILE" -w=$SIZEWIDTH -h=$SIZEHEIGHT

    else 
        echo "File does not exist."
    fi

}


# go!

exportFile $1 36 "drawable-ldpi"
exportFile $1 48 "drawable-mdpi"
exportFile $1 72 "drawable-hdpi"
exportFile $1 96 "drawable-xhdpi"
exportFile $1 144 "drawable-xxhdpi"

echo DONE baby!
```